# Javascript - Workaround for flatmap

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, flatmap

So I was looking for some workaround for flat map as it doesn't work on IE and I find this one:
But I don't really understand why does it work

```
var gadjets = [
  {computers:['asus', 'hp'],
  sellphones:['Galaxy', 'Nokia']
  },

  {computers:['dell', 'insys'],
  sellphones:['iphone', 'samsung']
  }
];

const getValues = gadjets.reduce((acc, gadjet) => acc.concat(gadjet[computers]), []) // instead of gadjets.flatMap(gadjet=> gadjet[computers])
```

This code returns:

```
['asus','hp','dell','insys']
```

But shouldn't it return:

```
['asus','hp'],['dell', 'insys']
```

Comment: u are using concat and not push that's why it's plain array(simply concatenating)

Comment: You can find polyfills for `flatMap`. There's one in [`core-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) (which is a bit strapped for a maintainer at the moment), there's one in the [`es-shims` project](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.flatMap), ...

Comment: @PranavCBalan - The above *wants* `concat`.

Comment: *"But shouldn't it return"* What is that? You've shown two distinct values but no container around them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : yes but he is confused why the output is plain array instead of nested

Comment: @PranavCBalan ahh I think I get it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `reduce` adds up the elements you give it. For example, take the following code:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.reduce((before, value)=>before+value));
```

This code takes each `value` and adds it to `before`. It then passes that added value into the next iteration of `reduce`, in the `before` variable.

In your code, you were passing an *array* into `before`, or in your case `acc`, and concatenates (merge) a new array from `gadgets['computers']` and returns that array. This creates a list of the computers from the array of objects.

More info on `reduce` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Answer (score 1):

> But shouldn't it return

I'm not sure what you're trying to show us there, but if you mean

```
[['asus','hp'],['dell', 'insys']]
```

then no, it shouldn't. `concat` flattens arrays you pass it (to a single level):

```js
const a = [].concat(['asus','hp'], ['dell', 'insys']);
console.log(a); // ["asus", "hp", "dell", "insys"]
```

So `acc.concat(gadjet[computers])` flattens out each of those `computers` arrays into a new array, which is the accumulation result of the `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the output to be array of arrays. Try this:

```js
var gadjets = [
  { computers: ["asus", "hp"], sellphones: ["Galaxy", "Nokia"] },
  { computers: ["dell", "insys"], sellphones: ["iphone", "samsung"] }
];
const groupBy = key => {
  let res = gadjets.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
               let arr = [];
               arr.push(obj[key]);
               return objectsByKeyValue.concat(arr);
        }, []);
   return res;
};
console.log(groupBy("computers"));
```